# jQueryUI 2 tabs inside another tab - height isn't set when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

The app I'm developing has a number of main pages which I'm implementing using jQueryUI tabs with `heightStyle:"fill"` so they all extend to the full height of the container on the web page.  One of these pages contains two more tabs elements, again created with `heightStyle:"fill"`.  I want them to appear side-by-side so I've wrapped each one in a `<div>` with `height:100%` `width:50%` `position:absolute` `top:0`, then one has `left:0` and the other has `right:0` to make them stick to the right edges of the container.  JSfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/v9vrb5qs/).

The problem I'm seeing is that if tab "1" is selected when the page loads, and I then click on tab "2", the two inner tabs element display with the wrong height.

I only get the problem if "1" is the default tab.  If I make it "2" by changing the `active` option in the `tabs()` call to 1 then the elements are visible when the page loads and their height is set correctly.

The problem goes away if you run the "refresh" method on the inner tabs because this causes them to recalculate their height, so one way of solving this is to run "refresh" from a "tabsactivate" event handler on the outer-tabs element.  The problem is that this event handler is triggered for ALL tabs, not just the one we're interested in.  So how do I use callbacks to handle this efficiently.

Another way of fixing it is to change the CSS, as I suspect the problem is being caused by wrapping the inner tabs in a div with "position:absolute".

Suggestions gratefully received!!

Comment: Maybe I was trying to hard - setting

`#inner-tabs-A, #inner-tabs-B {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

gets the height set correctly when panel-2 is hidden.  See http://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/L96xyL5n/

Comment: Oh no it doesn't!  Setting the height of the 'tabs' container apparent gets the panel to display with the correct height, but the <div> has a style="height:..." attribute that remains wrong, causing the content to be truncated and an overflow scrollbar to be applied.  Maybe I need to set the height of the individual panel <div>s...

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it!  First bind a custom `my-activate` event handler to the panel that contains the inner 'tabs' elements, and from there send them a `refresh` event.  Second, add an `activate` event handler to the outer 'tabs' element and from there pass the `my-activate` event to the activated child panel.  http://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/a92rg8cy/.  The neat thing with this approach is that you can bind a different handler to each child panel.

Another possibility is that you can send a custom `my-deactivate` event to the panel that's being deselected (using ui.oldPanel) so it can switch off any background update processing that it had put in place when it was activated.

Take care because the `activate` event isn't sent to the 'tabs' element when it first appears on the screen - you only get it when the selected panel changes.  If you need to do something first time, handle the `create` event instead - http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create.  Enjoy!